# Lance GG : Is it posible to activate game pause?

Tags: lance

Is it possible to add pause function to the game.
Without setting all DynamicObject velocity to 0. E.g. the pong game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lance is a multiplayer game engine, so it wouldn't make sense to pause the game just for a single client - as the game must continue for all other players.

Nevertheless, there is an `ignorePhysics` attribute on the `GameEngine` class.  Setting this attribute to `true` on the server would stop the physics, and should work in interpolation mode.

Answer (score 0):

To some extent, it would make sense with a global pause feature. Think any modern MOBA - if a client disconnects, the game is paused to wait for a reconnect. Unless of course, Lance.gg is only meant for persistent worlds :)